# Как вывести свежие записи не на главной странице в Wordpress 5.3.2

Tags: wordpress

Всем привет.
У меня вопрос, как вывести последние записи в Wordpress, не главной странице, а на другой, имея Шаблон который я написал.

**Вот как я пытался:**

Создал файлик с именем "template_page_news.php".
Прописал в нем то что необходимо для Шаблона страниц.
Прописал все что необходимо для вывода постов.
Но когда перехожу на эту страницу, ничего не выводится, возможно для этого типа записей(Стандартные новости, или еще называется свежие записи) должно быть нужное имя файлика?

```
<?php
/*
    Template Name: Шаблон - Новости
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php if (function_exists('add_theme_support')) the_post_thumbnail(array(0, 9999), array('class' => 'd-none post_thumbnail')); ?>
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; /* rewind or continue if all posts have been fetched */ ?>
<?php else : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php the_posts_pagination(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Попробовал добавить код в файл индекса так-как он был пустой и главная страница у меня также выводилась через шаблон, это сработало, но все-же хотелось бы чтоб в отдельном файле выводилась верстка с записями.

Comment: Создайте в админке страницу и выберите для неё шаблон, который вы создали. После этого на созданной вами странице будет отрабатывать созданный вами шаблон

Comment: Да, но как записи туда протянуть? Шаблон обработается, но выводиться будет название именно этой страницы а не цикл записей.

Comment: Почитайте о wp_query() (например, здесь https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/)

Comment: Вы каждую свою задачу будет писать на SO? Может все-таки поискать в гугле проще?